# how to create a list of lists while swaping items from original list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to generate a list of lists by swapping items in a list. I need to start by swapping one with every item in the list. Then I have to go back to the original list and start swapping two with every item. for example.

```
L0 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
L1 = [2, 1, 3, 4]
L2 = [3, 2, 1, 4]
L3 = [4, 2, 3, 1]
```

Then I start swapping 2 from the original list L1

```
L4 = [1, 3, 2, 4]
L5 = [1, 4, 3, 2]
```

How can I create something like this in python?

Comment: Can you share your first attempt with your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested for loops with list slicing:

```
L0 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
res = []
for i in range(len(L0) - 1):
  for j in range(i + 1, len(L0)):
    swappedList = L0[:i] + [L0[j]] + L0[i+1:j] + [L0[i]] + L0[j+1:]
    res.append(swappedList)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 1, 3, 4], [3, 2, 1, 4], [4, 2, 3, 1], [1, 3, 2, 4], [1, 4, 3, 2], [1, 2, 4, 3]]
```

A little explanation:

- `L0[:i]`: Elements from the first to the `i-1`-th.
- `[L0[j]]`: `j`-th element, we use `j` rather than `i` for swapping.
- `L0[i+1:j]`: Elements from the `i+1`-th to the `j-1`-th.
- `[L0[i]]`: `i`-th element, we use `i` rather than `j` for swapping.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work

```
res = [a[:]]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(a)):
        a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
        res.append(a[:])
        a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard library: itertools.permutations

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations